# Post Checkbox Value For Multiple Delete From Database

Tags: jquery, sql, database, post

Screenshot: [image]

I want to delete rows from database with jQuery as on the screenshot. I watch more than 150 tutorials about jQuery. But I'm rookie. I know the usage of jquery post. But I couldn't handle it exactly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $('#cart_delete_button').click(function(){
                            var deleteditems = $('input:checkbox[name="delete_cart[]"]:checked')
                                    .map(function() { return $(this).val() })
                                    .get()
                                    .join(",");
                           //alert(deleteditems);
                           $.post('post.php',{deleteditems: deleteditems},function(data){
                               $('.loading').text(data);
                           });
                        });
                    </script>
```

I wrote this code for deleting but I want to remove tr instantly. How can I do that?

Comment: post more about how you generate this table. That would be the best way we can be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty tough job, especially when lesser information is provided. But someone has to do it...
Anyway...

First,

1) You must be populating your table with the values from the database.
2) While constructing, assign DATABASE ID of each row to the checkbox element.

When you click the checkbox, get it ID of selected checkbox and pass it to the database via $.ajax and do your deletion operations there...

The problem is not TOTALLY of jQuery. Both the PHP and jQuery need to be used to in some interesting way. No amount of DVD watching and book reading will help you. You MUST get your hands dirty with this.

Also, First think of what you want to do. List all the usecase, decide a firm approach and then start coding stuff. It helps in long run.

How do solve the problem?

Assuming you are constructing your table with data returned from server in JSON format.

Lets say yout JSON is

```
var json =  {
        "data": [
            {
                "itemID": "1",
                "itemName": "Item Name1"
            },
            {
                "itemID": "2",
                "itemName": "Item Name2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

While constructing your table,

When you create a checkbox
do it like

```
for(var i=0;i<json.data.length;i++){
var cBox = jQuery("<inout />",{type="checkbox",id=json.data[i].itemId});
$("#yourTargetID").append(cBox);
}
```

Attach `check` handler to these elements to make ajax call.

Like

```
$("#cBoxId").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked'=='checked')){
        $.post('yourphpfile.php',{data:$(this).attr(id)},function(data){
            if(data==1){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove(); // just a placeholder as I do not know your exact DOM structure.
            }else {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On your PHP

```
$id = $_POST['data'];

$query = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE itemId = $id";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result){
    echo 1;
}
else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jqGrid (or any other jquery based grids) for this purpose.
Its pretty simple and straightforward.

[Here](http://krams915.blogspot.in/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html) is the tutorial for Spring based management.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When generating html using for example PHP - You get rows from DB and use primary key column values to asign ids to checkboxes, after You use :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'delete.php',
    data : {row_id: $(this).attr('id')},
    success : function() {
      $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //or whatever html you use for displaying rows
    }
  });
});
```

In delete.php:

```
$id = $_POST['row_id'];
if (mysql_query("DELTE FROM TABLE WHERE id = $id")) echo 'OK';
else echo 'FAIL'
```